# Unrecognized selector sent to instance - why?

Tags: objective-c, ios

OK so I have a code with an class object called "game". Every frame (60 FPS) I update that object with function that gets a string. After like 5 seconds of running the game I'm getting the unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

The update:

```
[game updatePlayersAndMonsters:@"0" monsters:@"0"];
```

The function:

```
-(void)updatePlayersAndMonsters:(NSString*)players monsters:(NSString*)monsters {
    CCLOG(@"%@.%@", players, monsters);
}
```

I don't understand what's going on.
The error:

```
2011-07-03 12:13:19.175 app[65708:207] -[NSCFString updatePlayersAndMonsters:monsters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc4e95b0
2011-07-03 12:13:19.176 app[65708:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString updatePlayersAndMonsters:monsters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc4e95b0'
```

What should I do? Thanks. Also IDK if any other details you need, so just write if I forget something, I just don't have an idea.

UPDATE:
Gmae is object of class GameNode:

```
    +(id) GmameNodeWithMapID:(int)MapID_ scene:(SomeScene*)MainScene_ players:(NSString*)Cplayers_ monsters:(NSString*)Cmonsters_ monsterCount:(NSString*)monsterCount_
{
    return [[[self alloc] GmameNodeWithMapID:MapID_ scene:MainScene_ players:Cplayers_ monsters:Cmonsters_ monsterCount:monsterCount_] autorelease];
}
-(id) GmameNodeWithMapID:(int)MapID scene:(SomeScene*)MainScene players:(NSString*)Cplayers monsters:(NSString*)Cmonsters monsterCount:(NSString*)monsterCount
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
```

I create it with:

```
game = [GameNode GmameNodeWithMapID:ChoosenMapID scene:self players:Thing[5] monsters:Thing[6] monsterCount:Thing[4]];
```

UPDATE 2

I create the SomeScene:

```
+(id) scene {
    CCScene *s = [CCScene node];
    id node = [SomeScene node];
    [s addChild:node];
    return s;
}
-(id) init {
    if( (self=[super init])) {
```

I use it:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [CCTransitionRadialCW transitionWithDuration:1.0f scene:[LoginScene scene]]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString updatePlayersAndMonsters:monsters:]:` means tht you are trying to send updatePlayersAndMonsters to a String object. Are you reassigning `game` to point to something else?

Comment: OK that's really weird... Hmm I don't think I do, sorry for being noob - what do you mean by reassigning to point to somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of ways to get this kind of error. One way is indadvertedly doing something like this: `game = <some other object>`. Another way (and probably more likely given your latest update), is that the game object got released, and the memory location that used to contain your game object now contains something else.

Comment: The instruments tool in xcode is really helpful for debugging this kind of thing. If you can run it in the simulator then try running it with the Zombies instrument. This tool will tell you when you send a message to an object that has been released, and it will show you all the allocs/retains/releases/autoreleases to help you find where you've over-released (or under-retained)

Comment: Using zombies gives me nothing. But the third comment - how can I resolve that if so? When zombies not working - it just does not shows nothing after crashed.

Answer (score 3):

Since you imply that the update function `[game updatePlayersAndMonsters:@"0" monsters:@"0"];` is called for the first 5 seconds of your game and then you get the error, my guess is that the `game` object is not correctly retained, so it gets deallocated and the successive attempt of sending a message to it fails because some `NSString` object has been reusing its memory (and it does not have a `updatePlayersAndMonsters:monsters` selector).

Please share how `game` is created (alloc/init) and how it is stored in your classes to help you further.

Activating NSZombies tracking could also help to diagnose this.

EDIT: after you adding the code

It seems to me that in the line:

```
 game = [GameNode GmameNodeWithMapID:ChoosenMapID scene:self players:Thing[5] monsters:Thing[6] monsterCount:Thing[4]];
```

you are setting either a local variable or an ivar to your autoreleased `GameNode`.

Now, since you are not using a property, nor I can see any retain on your autoreleased `GameNode`, my hypothesis seems confirmed. Either assign to a retain property:

```
self.game = [GameNode ...];
```

being game declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)...
```

or do a retain yourself:

```
 game = [[GameNode GmameNodeWithMapID:ChoosenMapID scene:self players:Thing[5] monsters:Thing[6] monsterCount:Thing[4]] retain];
```

Comment: I'm trying with zombies but every time it just crashes and then does not shows the object or anything... That's weird.. I'm using Xcode 4 > Product > profile > Zombies.. It always works but now it's just simple crashes and nothing more..

Comment: OK so add the retain but still the autorelease? Also sometimes I need to remove the game object and create a new one, so I do it exactly the same with retain? Thanks!!

Comment: Send a release? what do you mean..? Also I've added the retain and still the same error same thing..

Comment: Your code is still wrong, it's:                    ` game = [[GameNode GmameNodeWithMapID:ChoosenMapID scene:self players:Thing[5] monsters:Thing[6] monsterCount:Thing[4]] retain]; `
 But still I have the error.

Comment: You mean to the function dealloc? I added but it doesn't stops. Also yea same error.

Comment: I don't understand.. How to get that value?

Comment: This NSLog gives me error: conversion specificies type 'unsigned int' but theargument has type 'GameNode *'

Comment: Sorry for being noob - how to? If I'm doing                     CCLOG(@"game: %@", game);
 it pasts me:  game: <GameNode = 0C0BBD50 | Tag = -1> while t=in the error the memory location is 0x56b81b0

Comment: Hmmm it's a cocos2d scene.. I don't know actually.

Comment: Thanks. There is something I am missing... do you mean that `SomeScene` does `game = [GameNode...`? game is an ivar defined in SomeScene? What is the relationship between SomeScene and LoginScene?

Comment: So, check that SomeScene is not deallocated at some point before the error happens by putting a breakpoint in its `dealloc`...